# Adding a value weekly

Tags: php

I wanted to see if I can change the value number of several texts weekly without the use of a database. Just with the use of PHP

For instance, on the website you see the following

- Game 265
- Game 264
- Game 263
- Game 262

1 Week later I want the numbers to add 1 and change to

- Game 266
- Game 265
- Game 264
- Game 263

Comment: And what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Create a PHP script to search for and modify the text in the file, and then call the PHP script on a weekly basis using a CRON job.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do this by counting the number of weeks between the current date and some arbitrary date in the past. So, since today is 5/21/2012, if you counted the weeks since 5/7/2012 you would get 2. If you wanted to start the counting at 266 you could do:
    $weeksSinceDate + 264

::UPDATE::
In response to your question, here is some code you could use:

```
$counterStartNum = 266;
$date1 = new DateTime("2012-05-21");
$date2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$weeksSinceDate = $interval->d / 7;
$currentCounter = $counterStartNum + $weeksSinceDate;
```

Comment: Would this be correct? $initial_date = strtotime('2012-05-21');
$initial_value = 266;

$new_value = $initial_value + 1;